# restrict input type file to a specific location

Tags: html, input

I am doing html pages with forms, one of them got an `input type="file"`

The question is, **is it possible to restrict the location of browsing for a file?**

What I mean is when a user choose a file, he is only allowed to choose files from this location `C:\reports`

Here is my code if needed:

```
<form method="post" action="./../asp/upload_memo.asp">
<input required="required" name="dname" type="file" accept=".doc,.docx"  />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Tried searching for an answer but couldn't find.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there is no way to do that

Comment: No, that is browser's job and user preference, not possible as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. You had to be aware of the clients filesystem and privacy policy [actively prevents it](http://martinivanov.net/2009/06/09/the-mystery-of-cfakepath-unveiled/).